# Show URLs inside list with lxml.builder

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lxml

I have a need to generate HTML with `lxml` package. Here is the sample `main` function that shows how I do it:

```
def main():
    from lxml.builder import E

    p_persons = []
    person = ['1']  #counter
    person.append('ID')
    person.append('0. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLsn5aNaVkI 1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPbO6P3Vtx8 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVKWPaFuNng 3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HFyB4gCOqY 4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muQGef4Df_8')
    person.append('birthplace')
    p_persons.append(person)

    page = (
    E.html(
        E.body(
        E.table(
                *[E.tr(
                     *[
                        E.td(split(col)) if ind == 1 and col is not None else
                        E.td(str(col)) for ind, col in enumerate(row)
                     ]
                     ) for row in p_persons ]
                , border="2"
                )
            )
        )
    )

    with open('result.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(etree.tostring(page, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))

def split(col):
    from lxml.builder import E
    import re

    muts = re.split('\d\.',col)
    links = []
    for idx, mut in enumerate(muts):
        print(mut)
        links.append(str(idx + 1))
        links.append(E.a(mut, href=mut))
        links.append('\n')
    return links
```

All is fine with simple structures like above, but sometimes I need to analyze the data and output it to `E.td` depending on the content.

I build `person` element which is a list of fields, and than put it to `p_persons` list, intended for output. Second field (a string which contains URLs separated by counter) demonstrates us the structure to be output. It is necessary to split this string and show the URLs in a form of a numeric list inside **single** cell `E.td`.

But `E.td` doesn't recognize it, if I put `E.td(split(col))`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/home/user/functions.py", line 298, in rows_to_html
) for row in rows ]
  File "/home/user/functions.py", line 298, in <listcomp>
) for row in rows ]
  File "/home/user/functions.py", line 296, in <listcomp>
  E.td(str(col)) for ind, col in enumerate(row)
  File "src/lxml/builder.py", line 222, in  lxml.builder.ElementMaker.__call__
TypeError: bad argument type: list(['1', <Element a at 0x7f1900117c48>, '\n'])
```

Here is the HTML sample I want to receive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table border="2">
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><ol>
            <li>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLsn5aNaVkI</li>
            <li>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPbO6P3Vtx8</li>
            <li>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVKWPaFuNng</li>
            <li>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HFyB4gCOqY</li>
            <li>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muQGef4Df_8</li>
            </ol>  
        </td>
        <td>birthplace</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the proper way of doing this? Should I wrap the URLs into `DIV` or smth else? I didn't find similar examples in the web.

Comment: Show us the code of `rows_to_html`.

Comment: @LutzHorn, added the code

Comment: Even better would be a single chunk of code that we can copy, paste, and run directly. In short, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added single `main` function

Comment: Yep, I missed the bracket in the unpack statement. Corrected, sorry. Now it should throw only the above traceback.